# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. After changing loading state to context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I changed my isLoading state to a context provider and this error occurred 
`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setIsLoading'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

The app works just as before. I would like to understand this warning.

Heres my code:

```js
const { isLoading, setIsLoading } = useContext(LoadingContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountries = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await axios(`${baseUrl}`);
      setCountries(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getCountries();
  }, []);
```

Edit: Ive add [setIsLoading] to the last array and the warning has disappeared. 
I would still love to know why this warning appeared and why I must add setIsLoading to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` depends on a variable that is defined outside of the `useEffect` and inside your component. That variable is `setIsLoading`. You should declare it as a dependency in the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCountries = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await axios(`${baseUrl}`);
      setCountries(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getCountries();
  }, [setIsLoading]); // declare it here
```

To see why declaring dependencies is important, check out the [React effect hook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), specifically '[Why Effects Run on Each Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update)' and '[Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)'.

Basically, your `useEffect` needs to know about its dependencies incase those dependencies change.

From the docs:

> ...make sure the array includes **all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect.** Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders...